# Как в цикле выбрать все дочерние записи?

Tags: php

Таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как в цикле вытащить всю цепочку например за записью где id найден в parent_fid

Вот пример моего кода.

```
        $array_folderid = array();
        $startfor = 0;
        $folderdel_id = "155";
        for($i=0;$i<=$startfor;$i++) {



$sql_selectfolders = "SELECT * FROM user_folders WHERE parent_fid='$folderdel_id' ";
$query_selectfolders = mysqli_query($db,$sql_selectfolders) or die("Ошибка: " . mysqli_error($db));

            if (mysqli_num_rows($query_selectfolders) > 0) {
                while ($fid = mysqli_fetch_array($query_selectfolders)) {
                    array_push($array_folderid, $fid["id"]);
                }
            }

        }
```

В этоге я получаю вот такой массив.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 156
    [1] => 159
)
```

Но как теперь повторить цикл с этими данным, то есть теперь мне нужно вытащить все id по тем что в массиве.И глубина может бить не предсказуема.

Сам решить эту задачку не смог, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: `И глубина может бить не предсказуема` в таком случае нужна рекурсия. Если только в рамках тестовой задачи - сойдёт. Но в рабочем приложении это будет тормозить.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, я для себя на локалке тринируюсь :)

Comment: Тогда ищите "рекурсивная выборка дерева SQL PHP" . Потому что ваша задача - это простое построение дерева из "плоской" таблицы - в общем то частая задача. При чём есть вариант с рекурсией на самом SQL . Я не буду отвечать - так как решений ну очень много можно нагуглить.

Comment: Делайте только один запрос к таблице, а дальше стройте из полученного массива дерево.

Comment: [ссылка (eng)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/46147). Как пишется в ответе, в mysql (а Вы так и не написали, какую базу используете) нет встроенных средств для выполнения рекурсивных запросов. Такая функциональность есть в postgre, например (и еще некоторых других). Но в общем случае вообще не рекомендуется хранить такие структуры в БД (как пишет там товарищ ниже). В 99% случаев можно обойтись без этого, нужно просто подумать как.